# I need example to satisfy in this theorem (Hall Subgroup)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I need example to satisfy in this theorem: let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ such that $\mid G : H \mid$ is a $\Pi$-number.If there is a nilpotent subgroup $K$ of $G$ such that $G=HK$ then $G=HK_{\Pi}$, where $K_{\Pi}$ is a $\Pi$-Hall subgroup of $K$.

Comment: You are searching an example where you can apply the theorem?

Comment: yes, i searching an example to can apply this theorem.

Comment: You have asked several question like this, and I don't think any of them make much sense. We could take both $H$ and $K$ to be the trivial group and $\Pi$ any set of primes. Or we could take $G=A_5$, $H$ trivial, and $\Pi = \{2,3,5\}$ - in that case, there is no nilpotent subgroup $K$ with $G=HK$, but the example still satisfies the theorem.